# Ionic folder RANDOMLY disappears from node_modules folder

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm, node-modules

Long story short: Ionic randomly disappears from my node_modules folder ALL THE TIME. I always seem to have problems with this folder. I must have something wrong in my file directory but I'm not sure what it is. Here's an example of what I did to cause it (removing a plugin).

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-facebook4
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-facebook4 --save
Uninstalling cordova-plugin-facebook4 from android

Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Uninstalling cordova-plugin-facebook4 from browser

js-module uninstall called : plugins\cordova-plugin-facebook4\www\facebook-native.js
js-module uninstall called : plugins\cordova-plugin-facebook4\www\facebook-browser.js
Uninstalling cordova-plugin-facebook4 from ios

Removing "cordova-plugin-facebook4"

Removing plugin cordova-plugin-facebook4 from config.xml file...

Removing cordova-plugin-facebook4 from package.json

Error: Cannot find module '../prepare'

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-facebook4 --save (exit code 1).
```

(of course it resulted in an error, why wouldn't it...but it did in fact seem to remove this plugin)

And then I try to re add the plugin:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --save
module.js:538
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\blah\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

The ionic folder is now missing from my node_modules, as well as a few others. This is virtually impossible to research, can anyone help me?? Thank you

Comment: How did you install Ionic? Locally in your project or globally?

Comment: I think I may have done both. It's a very long running project; since 2017 when I first started getting into it. If I were to install it locally it probably would be the node_modules/ionic folder correct?

Comment: Yes, but Ionic CLI usually works with a [local installation with `npm install -g ionic`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli). A new project created with `ionic start` also doesn't locally install Ionic CLI (`ionic`) into the project, so you are probably fine (and following the usual behavior) removing it locally and just using the global installation.